# SQL Server query help to update the row instead of inserting

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have two tables called t and t1 . 
Problem :
if no data is available in #t1 then i need to insert and if data is avialable then i need to update . suppose if i got blank first time in terminationdate column of #t1 from #t then i need to insert and if i get data with same active date with same id then i need to update date in  termination date  column of #t1 and i should not have 2 nd entry in table . how do i handle it.

```
CREATE TABLE #t (
id INT
,activedate VARCHAR(15)
,terminationdate VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #t1 (
id INT
,activedate VARCHAR(15)
,terminationdate VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES (
1
,'2006-01-01'
,NULL
)
,(
1
,'2006-01-01'
,'2006-01-31'
)

SELECT *
FROM #t

SELECT *
FROM #t1

MERGE INTO #t1 ds
USING (
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM #t
) al
ON ds.id = al.id
    AND ds.activedate = al.activedate
    AND ds.terminationdate = al.terminationdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT (
        id
        ,activedate
        ,terminationdate
        )
    VALUES (
        id
        ,activedate
        ,terminationdate
        )
WHEN MATCHED
AND ds.terminationdate = ''
THEN
    DELETE
WHEN MATCHED
AND ds.id = al.id
AND ds.activedate = al.activedate
THEN
    UPDATE
    SET ds.terminationdate = al.terminationdate;
```

Expected out put :

First time

```
id    activedate    terminationdate   
1    2006-01-01    null
```

IF i got terminationdate(assume 2006- 8-30) forsame id WITH same active DATE then record    should UPDATE instead OF 2 nd record entry

```
id activedate terminationdate      
1 2006-01 - 01 2006 - 8 - 30
```

Note :
IF we can achieve by altering the above query it will be great otherthewise share the alternative methods TO achive it.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is exactly what the [MERGE command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.105).aspx) was designed for. An example is:

```
MERGE dbo.Table1
USING dbo.Source ON Source.Key = Table1.Key

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Data1=Source.Data1, Data2=Source.Data2

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT
VALUES(Source.Key, Source.Data1, Source.Date2)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE

OUTPUT $Action, isnull(Source.Key,Table1.Key), 
   deleted.Data1,deleted.Data2,
   inserted.Data1,inserted.Data2;
```

Comment: in merge we can delete the records if matched only .

Comment: @Prasad:No, records unmatched by source can also be deleted (if desired) with SQL SERVER 2008 R2..